# MySQL query with join or subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have such a schema and queries:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b032/3

Seperately I have these queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'times', userid, name
FROM main
WHERE comedate <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),
                   INTERVAL 5 DAY)
GROUP BY userid ORDER BY times DESC LIMIT 0,2;

SELECT * FROM details WHERE 1;
```

By comparing userid columns of both table I need to join them.
I need an output having these columns:
"`times, userid, name, age, location`"
Also order, group and limits should be considered.

I would be happy if you can write one query with JOIN and one query with subquery.
I have a 60k table and I will compare the performances.

Comment: no need to compare performance, join wins. If join doesn't win, add an index and it will.

Comment: in seperate forums I read that subqueries are better if you have large tables, joins are better for small tables. my table has 60k rows inside it. so I'm curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
select x.times,
  x.userid,
  x.name,
  d.age,
  d.location
from 
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'times', userid, name
  FROM main
  WHERE comedate <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),
                     INTERVAL 5 DAY)
  GROUP BY userid 
) x
left join details d
  on x.userid = d.userid
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d6f9/4)

edit:

```
select x.times,
  x.userid,
  x.name,
  d.age,
  d.location
from 
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'times', userid, name
  FROM main
  WHERE comedate <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),
                     INTERVAL 5 DAY)
  GROUP BY userid
  ORDER BY times DESC 
  LIMIT 0,2
) x
left join details d
  on x.userid = d.userid
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d6f9/18)

Comment: ORDER BY times column and adding LIMIT?

Comment: @trante just found an error in my second version, please see my edit

Comment: thank you for help. is it possible to write it with a subquery style or is it not possible for this condition?

Comment: @trante write what with a subquery?